# There is a error, can somebody tell me what the error is in my code?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import random
i = 0
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange"]


while i < 5:
    print("You gotten a", random.choice(mylist))
i = i + 1
#I want to make it say 5 times
```

Comment: Please format the code, fix the indentation, and post the exact error with trace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to indent your `i = i + 1`.

```
import random
i = 0
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange"]


while i < 5:
    print("You gotten a", random.choice(mylist))
    i = i + 1
```

Also, in case you don't know, you can write `i = i + 1` like `i += 1`.

Comment: And also use a `for i in range(5)` instead of a while loop with a manual increment

Comment: I agree, but I think he just wanted to try out a `while loop`.